# Python/Tkinker Combobox event not launching

Tags: python, python-3.x, events, tkinter, callback

I'm pulling my hair out and sure I'll be embarrassed by how simple my mistake is. I have created a Combobox which is supposed to launch a function each time is it selected. However nothing happens when you pick a different selection.

Here's the code:

```
acc_drop_box = ttk.Combobox(mainframe, textvariable=acc_value)
acc_drop_box['values'] = acc_list
acc_drop_box.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=(W, E))
acc_drop_box.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', pick_acc(acc_value))
```

Right now the function "pick_acc" just prints the word "Hi!" for testing purposes. That happens once when I launch the program but not again no matter what I do. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You're giving the return of the callback as the reference as opposed to callback's reference. Replace:

```
acc_drop_box.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', pick_acc(acc_value))
```

with:

```
acc_drop_box.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', lambda var=acc_value: pick_acc(var))
```

Comment: This works! Awesome thanks. As for it being duplicate, I can see that it is. I didn't find this because I was looking for Combobox specifically.